# Notification.requestPermission() Issue

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

I am displaying a Desktop Notification using:

```
var notification = new Notification('hello', { body: "Hey there!" });
```

It's working fine on my local system. But on the live server it's not working and get below error:

> [Deprecation] The Notification API may no longer be used from insecure
>   origins. You should consider switching your application to a secure
>   origin, such as HTTPS. See goo.gl/rStTGz for more details.

Comment: Your website needs to be under an https url, not http. Get an SSL certificate.

Comment: This is a very clear deprecation notice. It says what the problem is and what you should do to prevent this message. What is your question?